# Bintray? issue build failed

Tags: java, android, android-studio, maven, gradle

I am not an android dev i know web dev and somewhat of android studio so i got an external dev to build an app for me which i just compile in android studio and ship the apk/obb to google play all was fine in Nov but in December i made a little edit in ui but when i tried to "Make project" the build failed giving this error.

From what i read bintray is no longer used but this dev uses it can anyone help understand this error and how to fix it.

the error:

```
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.venmo.view.tooltip:tooltip:0.1.2.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.venmo.view.tooltip:tooltip:0.1.2.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.125+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/venmo/view/tooltip/tooltip/0.1.2/tooltip-0.1.2.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/venmo/view/tooltip/tooltip/0.1.2/tooltip-0.1.2.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.faltenreich:skeletonlayout:2.0.1.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.faltenreich:skeletonlayout:2.0.1.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/faltenreich/skeletonlayout/2.0.1/skeletonlayout-2.0.1.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/faltenreich/skeletonlayout/2.0.1/skeletonlayout-2.0.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/facebook/shimmer/shimmer/0.5.0/shimmer-0.5.0.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/facebook/shimmer/shimmer/0.5.0/shimmer-0.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.zendesk.belvedere2:belvedere:3.0.0-RC.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.zendesk.belvedere2:belvedere:3.0.0-RC.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/zendesk/belvedere2/belvedere/3.0.0-RC/belvedere-3.0.0-RC.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/zendesk/belvedere2/belvedere/3.0.0-RC/belvedere-3.0.0-RC.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.yarolegovich:discrete-scrollview:1.5.1.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/yarolegovich/discrete-scrollview/1.5.1/discrete-scrollview-1.5.1.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/yarolegovich/discrete-scrollview/1.5.1/discrete-scrollview-1.5.1.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.126+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:7.0.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:7.0.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/7.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-7.0.0.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-sdk/7.0.0/facebook-android-sdk-7.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.shobhitpuri.custombuttons:google-signin:1.0.0.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/shobhitpuri/custombuttons/google-signin/1.0.0/google-signin-1.0.0.pom'.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]             > Could not HEAD 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/shobhitpuri/custombuttons/google-signin/1.0.0/google-signin-1.0.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :app
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Could not resolve com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828.
2021-12-16T00:30:13.127+0630 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          > Could not get resource 'http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven/com/squareup/picasso/picasso/2.71828/picasso-2.71828.pom'.
```

More go on like this but its too long to show here

This is the gradle script

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.21'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
//        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.0"

        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:2.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
plugins {
//    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version '1.4.21'
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/jlmd/maven" }
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

        }
        maven {
            url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
            credentials {
                username 'braintree_team_sdk'
                password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
            }
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://zendesk.jfrog.io/zendesk/oss-releases-local'

        }
        jcenter()
        google()

        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm"
```

Please help we are 6 days late on our update and i just need someone to help me. fi this post is wrong or need to fix something please tell me and i will fix it.

Comment: Bintray is out of service now. Refer to this https://blog.gradle.org/jcenter-shutdown

Comment: okay thanks @ping.shantanu i will try my best you helped me with the info tho :)